# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: filters, rest-api, https, http

I keep getting this error message when I am sending a fetch request from the admin side. I want to connect to that API and get some response.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://34557322456.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/V1/code?kdata=something' from origin 'https://mywebsite.online' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Is there a WordPress way to get it fixed?

Please help thanks

Tried these :

```
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origin', '__return_true' );
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');

add_filter('allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins');

function add_allowed_origins($origins) {
    $origins[] = 'https://34557322456.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com';
    $origins[] = 'https://34557322456.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/V1/code';
    return $origins;
}
```

this is the fetch request

```
 fetch('https://34557322456.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/V1/code?kdata=something', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This works but not the fetch method

```
$response = wp_remote_get('https://34557322456.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/V1/code?kdata=something');
        //var_dump($response);
    $responseBody = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
  $result = json_decode( $responseBody );
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: The resource mentioned in that message refers to the one on the site you're making the request to, i.e. the subdomain/site on `amazonaws.com`, whereas the origin is *your* site, i.e. `mywebsite.online`. So CORS needs to be enabled on the *resource*, which basically means you'd need to have control over the API. Nonetheless, check out [this article](https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin) and hopefully you'll understand why `wp_remote_get()` works, what CORS is, etc - if you still have questions, then try asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you I solved it. I was using a lambda function written in python it's response was not having the access-control-allow-origin.